# Rails nested route form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a category model that has many products. Here are the routes:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :products
end
```

I see a route in rake routes for category_product_new. When i try to create a new product I get error messages that there is no route for anything I have tried.

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>
```

Any thoughts on what I need to change with the form to allow me to submit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with:

```
# app/views/products/new.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: [@category, @product], local: true) do |form| %>
  // your code here
<% end %>
```

And in your `products_controller` you can try like this:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = Product.new
  end
end
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! That was it.